# I want to do junit test for execute function in spring batch. but having issue with the parameters chunkcontext and stepcontribution

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-batch

Wanted to do Junit test case on execute function in springbatch project, but i'm having issue on the parameter in the chunkcontext and stepcontribution. below code are the execute function itself.

```
public class tasklet implements Tasklet, InitializingBean {
private Resource directory;
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(directory, "directory must be set");
}


@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
                            ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("person.csv"));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Person p = new Person();
        String[] personnel = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        p.setFirstName(personnel[0]);
        p.setLastName(personnel[1]);
        session.save(p);
    }
    br.close();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println("Completed");
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
public Resource getDirectory() {
    return directory;
}

public void setDirectory(Resource directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
}
public static String asString(Resource directory) throws IOException {
    try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(directory.getInputStream(),UTF_8)){
        return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
    }catch (IOException e){
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Those parameters are not even used in your function.

Comment: i'm unable to do junit test to the above method. when i tried, it always return a nullpointerexception

Comment: You might want to add your JUnit test. Also add the stacktrace and make clear from which line the exception originates.